# Error while assigning a value to an array element

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kvm

**What I need to do:** 
Modify the Linux kernel code (3.13.6 downloaded from kernel.org). Find the number of times a kvm_vmx_exit_handler function is called.

**What I am trying to do:**
Declare an array in the file 'x86.h'

```
 extern unsigned long int my_count_s[40];
```

the file x86.h which is being included in the 'vmx.c' file

```
#include "x86.h"
```

Now, I am trying to initialise an element in the array to the value 0 in the file 'vmx.c'.

```
my_count_s[1] = 0;
```

I will be incrementing it each time when an kvm_exit_handler function is called. And I will get to know the number of times the kvm took an exit when something happened, and the number of times a particular exit handling function is called. I will be using a single element of the array for each of the exithandler function.

**Error I am facing:**

```
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c:58:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c:58:1: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘my_count_s’ [-Werror=implicit-int]
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c:58:1: error: conflicting types for ‘my_count_s’
arch/x86/kvm/x86.h:8:26: note: previous declaration of ‘my_count_s’ was here
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c:58:1: error: invalid initializer
```

**My understanding:** 
I have declared the datatype of my_count_s[40] to be an unsigned long int, but why is it being defaulted to 'int' ?
And even if it was defaulted ti data type 'int', why was there an initialization error for the line my_count_s[1] = 0; ?

**NOTE :** 1. Line 58 in vmx.c is the "my_count_s[1]=0;" 
2. If I compile the kernel by just declaring the array, it works fine but the errors popup while I am trying to assign a value to an element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements, including assignments have to be inside functions. I bet yours is outside a function.

The compiler is confused because `=` can only appear in declarations and statements, and since it's outside a function your line is parsed as a declaration. That just doesn't work; where's the type?

Comment: Sigh... good catch. The OP is trying to initialize the array with incorrect syntax.

Comment: @MSalters: Thankyou so much for pointing it out :) I was using python a lot and got used to assign values to the variables outside functions.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that, even though you have this in your header file:

```
extern unsigned long int my_count_s[40];
```

you still haven't *defined* the array anywhere - you've only *declared* that it exists *somewhere*.

In some source file (probably `arch/x6/kvm/vmx.c`), you need to *define* the array:

```
unsigned long int my_count_s[40];
```

---

Remember, `extern` says "Hey compiler, this variable exists in some module." That's why we put `extern` *declarations* in header files. They don't actually cause any space to be allocated for the variable, they just indicate its existence.

The line without `extern` is the *definition*, and is put in a `.c` file. It is in that compilation unit that space is actually reserved for the variable.

---

On another note. Does this variable *need* to be globally-scoped? If `arch/x6/kvm/vmx.c` is the only file that references it, then it should not be in the header file, and should be marked as `static` in the `.c` file:

```
static unsigned long int my_count_s[40];
```

Here, `static` limits its visibility to only the C file that it is defined in.

Comment: so should I use `unsigned long int my_count_s[40];` in the header file ,
and then use `unsinged long int my_count_s[40];` in the vmx.c file,
and then use `my_count_s[1] = 0;` to assign value to the second element in the array ??

Comment: No no no. Do not put global variable definitions in the header file! That will cause the variable to be defined in *every* C file that includes it.

Comment: I have tried declaring the array and using it in the vmx.c file and I have faced the same error (same errors while assigning value to the element in array), and so I have followed this approach suggested by a friend of mine.

Comment: I'm not sure what your friend suggested, but you have the entire kernel source as a good example in front of you. It's simple: *declarations* (i.e. function prototypes and `extern`'d global variables) go in header files, while *definitions* (functions with bodies, and global variables) go in .C files.

Comment: The first thing I did was to declare the array in the vmc.c file using 'static unsigned long int my_count_s[40];' and then assign a value of an element using `my_count_s[40];`. I was getting the same errors (`type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘my_count_s’` and `conflicting types for ‘my_count_s’` and `invalid initializer`)

Comment: Did you put this global at the top of the file? Also, you don't have `my_count_s[1] = 0;` *outside* of a function, do you?

Comment: yeah the declaration was at the top of the file. My bad I got used to assign values outside the functions and didnt realise it dosent work in C. Thankyou for your time. Your comments did really help me about using the header files. :)